# Chrome extension notification not displaying

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Simply that. The [chrome.notifications.create](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications) is not doing anything.

I have downloaded and ran Google's sample app (the toast and the water popup) https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/notifications.zip

The code is being hit, but nothing is appearing. In the chrome://extensions/ the extension has 'Display notifications' in the permissions.

OSX, Version 80.0.3987.132

EDIT: Ugh. It was due to the fact that I did not have notifications enabled for Chrome in my actual Macbook settings